# Write a class variable in a Label in main

Tags: python, class, tkinter, global

I want to write the variable of a class in a label I created in my main, but I am not able to get the updated value.
Maybe someone can help me, because I ran out of ideas.

```
from Tkinter import *

class CounterAway(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):        
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
        self.countera = 0
        self.ca = 0
        self._update_counter()

def _update_counter(self):
    self.ca = self.countera       

def count_up(self):
    self.countera += 1
    if self.countera > 99 : self.countera = 0
    self._update_counter()

def count_down(self):
    self.countera -= 1
    if self.countera < 0 : self.countera = 0
    self._update_counter()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()  
    """root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))"""
    root.geometry('1000x1000')  
    counteraway = CounterAway(root)



Button(root, font=('Arial',30), width=10, text='Away +', command=counteraway.count_up).place(x=450, y=300)   
Button(root, font=('Arial',30), width=10, text='Away -', command=counteraway.count_down).place(x=450, y=370)
Button(root, width=10, font=('Arial',30), text='Quit', command=root.destroy).place(x=10, y=10)
counteraway.label = Label(root, font="Arial 100 bold", fg="RED", text=str(counteraway.ca)).pack()

print(counteraway.ca)

root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Many thanks in advance for any help.

br
KlaRo

Comment: I don't understand much about `Tkinter`, so that's just a guess: when you run that code, everything outside a block will be executed first, then the code inside that `if` will be executed. So could the `couteraway` variable inside `main` been overwrited and losing the previous `label` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define root inside main() and then try to use it outside this function which will mean the code will throw an exception. It also seems that the indentation for the defined class is incorrect, if you change the code to the following it should run:

```
from Tkinter import *

class CounterAway(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):        
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
        self.countera = 0
        self.ca = 0
        self._update_counter()

    def _update_counter(self):
        self.ca = self.countera       

    def count_up(self):
        self.countera += 1
        if self.countera > 99 : self.countera = 0
        self._update_counter()

    def count_down(self):
        self.countera -= 1
        if self.countera < 0 : self.countera = 0
        self._update_counter()


def main():
    root = Tk()
    w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()  
    """root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))"""
    root.geometry('1000x1000')  
    counteraway = CounterAway(root)

    Button(root, font=('Arial',30), width=10, text='Away +', command=counteraway.count_up).place(x=450, y=300)   
    Button(root, font=('Arial',30), width=10, text='Away -', command=counteraway.count_down).place(x=450, y=370)
    Button(root, width=10, font=('Arial',30), text='Quit', command=root.destroy).place(x=10, y=10)
    counteraway.label = Label(root, font="Arial 100 bold", fg="RED", text=str(counteraway.ca)).pack()

    print(counteraway.ca)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you are wanting to update the text in the label you should look into Tkinter Variables for example the Tkinter StringVar. The code would look something like this:

```
from Tkinter import *

class CounterAway(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):        
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
        self.countera = 0
        self.ca = StringVar()
        self._update_counter()

    def _update_counter(self):
        self.ca.set(str(self.countera))       

    def count_up(self):
        self.countera += 1
        if self.countera > 99 : self.countera = 0
        self._update_counter()

    def count_down(self):
        self.countera -= 1
        if self.countera < 0 : self.countera = 0
        self._update_counter()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()  
    """root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))"""
    root.geometry('1000x1000')  
    counteraway = CounterAway(root)

    Button(root, font=('Arial',30), width=10, text='Away +', command=counteraway.count_up).place(x=450, y=300)   
    Button(root, font=('Arial',30), width=10, text='Away -', command=counteraway.count_down).place(x=450, y=370)
    Button(root, width=10, font=('Arial',30), text='Quit', command=root.destroy).place(x=10, y=10)
    counteraway_label = Label(root, font="Arial 100 bold", fg="RED", textvariable=counteraway.ca).pack()

    print(counteraway.ca)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```